# Auto Create new superUser for new teanants created in django

Tags: django

I tried this solution also but it is creating user in public schema only not in tenant schema .
I am using djnago-tenant to create a new tenant.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from tenant_schemas.utils import tenant_context
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@receiver(post_save, sender=Client):
def create_superuser(instance, **kwargs):
  if 'created' in kwargs: # tests if this client was created
    tenant=instance
    with tenant_context(tenant):
    # Create the superuser by using the new client tenant schema
      User.objects.create_user(
        # insert your user data here
      )
```

Let me know what should i do or any other way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

just replace `create_user` with `create_superuser`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Client):
def create_superuser(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    tenant=instance
    with tenant_context(tenant):
      User.objects.create_superuser(
        # insert your user data here
      )
```